# How can I upgrade OS X.11 to OS X.12 when the App Store only offers OS X.13

Tags: macos, upgrade, mac-appstore

I have a Mac running the latest version of OS 10.12. I need to upgrade this Mac to the latest version of OS 10.12. Although the hardware will support OS 10.13, for other, important reasons I am not able to perform an upgrade to 10.13 at this time.

I do not mind intermediate steps as necessary, such as upgrading to 10.12.0 and then updating to 10.12.latest.

Unfortunately, the App Store is only offering High Sierra. This is true both on the Update page and when I do a search in the App Store.

Without third-party tools, if possible, or if necessary then with minimal third-party tools and files, how can I upgrade this Mac to 10.12.latest  with the same outcome as though it had been upgraded through the App Store when 10.12 was still available?

Thanks.

Comment: I primarily use [Hackintosh Computer's website](https://www.hackintosh.computer/199/direct-download-macos/) to download older versions of macOS, but **I do not recommend installing versions from this website on your machine**, because they might be modified, even though they say it's not. I use them with Parallels virtual machines. By the way, **I do not use a hackintosh**.

Comment: it may still work:   https://itunes.apple.com/app/macos-sierra/id1127487414?mt=12